# Text of two strings not matching on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, comparison, string-comparison

## Objective

- I'm trying to compare the text of two strings — the first being the
  text in a list containing spans. It's default text reads "Pick a defenseman" and then the name of the player just clicked.
- The aim is to make it so that names of hockey players clicked on only
  replace the default text and **get added to this list once, as opposed to multiple times.**

## Problem

When I `console.log()` I still see the default text, despite the player's name being added to the span. As a result, when I used an if-statement that included `spanText !== playerName` I'm still able to add the same player multiple times, but I'm unsure why this is only happening with `.player--defenseman` not the other positions

### scripts.js

```
$(".player").click(function(){

    // Select the current player
    var player = $(this);

    // Count number of players of each position that have been clicked
    var pickedF = $(".player--forward.is-selected").length;
    var pickedD = $(".player--defenseman.is-selected").length;
    var pickedG = $(".player--goalie.is-selected").length;

    // Grab the name of the player last clicked
    playerName = player.find(".player__name").text();

    // Literally magic.
    $(".btn--add").unbind("click");

    $(".btn--add").click(function(){

        // Ensures names don't match
        var spanText = $(".player__pick").eq(0).text();

        // Changes the opacity of a picked player to 0.5
        player.addClass("is-selected");

        if (player.hasClass("player--forward")) {
            if (spanText !== playerName) {
                $(".player__pick--forward.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
                $(".player__pick--forward.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");

                if (pickedF < 2) {
                    pickedF++;
                }

                if (pickedF === 2) {
                    $(".player--forward").not(":has(.is-selected)").css("pointer-events", "none");
                    console.log("Locked forwards");
                } else {
                    $(".player--forward").css("pointer-events", "auto");
                }
            }
        }

        // Something is wonky here
        if (player.hasClass("player--defenseman")) {
            if (spanText !== playerName) {
                $(".player__pick--defenseman.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
                $(".player__pick--defenseman.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");

                console.log(spanText);
                console.log(playerName);

                if (pickedD < 3) {
                    pickedD++;
                }

                if (pickedD === 3) {
                    $(".player--defenseman").not(":has(.is-selected)").css("pointer-events", "none");
                    console.log("Locked defensemen");
                } else {
                    $(".player--defenseman").css("pointer-events", "auto");
                }
            }
        }

        if (player.hasClass("player--goalie")) {
            if (spanText !== playerName) {
                $(".player__pick--goalie.is-empty").eq(0).html(playerName);
                $(".player__pick--goalie.is-empty").eq(0).removeClass("is-empty");

                if (pickedG < 1){
                    pickedG++;
                }

                if (pickedG === 1) {
                    $(".player--goalie").not(":has(.is-selected)").css("pointer-events", "none");
                    console.log("Locked goalie");
                } else {
                    $(".player--goalie").css("pointer-events", "auto");
                }
            }
        }

        console.log(pickedF, pickedD, pickedG);
    });
```

## index.html

```
// List
            <ul>
                <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--forward is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a forward</span></li>
                <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--forward is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a forward</span></li>
                <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--defenseman is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a defenseman</span></li>
                <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--defenseman is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a defenseman</span></li>
                <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--defenseman is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a defenseman</span></li>
                <li><span class="player__pick player__pick--goalie is-empty"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick a goalie</span></li>
            </ul>

// Popup with Add to Team button
    <div class="popup clearfix">
        <div class="icon-container">
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <img src="" alt="" class="popup__picture animated">

        <div class="popup__text">
            <p class="popup__position">tk-position</p>
            <p class="popup__name">tk-name</p>
            <p class="popup__years">tk-years</p>
            <p class="popup__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi ad dicta sunt unde, sed quae nihil inventore voluptates nulla voluptate laudantium nesciunt quo, aspernatur deleniti quod harum, nisi error doloribus.</p>
            <div class="popup__stats">
                <p>tk-stats</p>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button class="btn--add">Add to team</button>
                <button class="btn--remove">Remove from team</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

// Players
        <div class="player player--pronger player--defenseman" data-id="16">
            <div class="player__info animated">
                <p class="player__name">Chris Pronger</p>
                <p class="player__position">Defenseman</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="player player--lefley player--forward" data-id="17">
            <div class="player__info animated">
                <p class="player__name">Chuck Lefley</p>
                <p class="player__position">Forward</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="player player--janney player--forward" data-id="18">
            <div class="player__info animated">
                <p class="player__name">Craig Janney</p>
                <p class="player__position">Forward</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="player player--joseph player--goalie" data-id="19">
            <div class="player__info animated">
                <p class="player__name">Curtis Joseph</p>
                <p class="player__position">Goalie</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Perhaps `playerName = player.find(".player__name").text();` needs to be `var playerName = player.find(".player__name").text();`

Comment: @haim770 Unfortunately, that did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
var spanText = $(".player__pick").eq(0).text();
```

it selects the first element with `player__pick` class.
That's why this:

```
if (spanText !== playerName) {
```

will always compare `playerName` to the **first element** with `player__pick` class. It won't check whether the target element is a *"defenseman"*, *"forward"*, or *"goalie"*.

---

Solution?

There're few ways to fix it. One of them is to check whether **any** of the `.player__pick` elements [**`contains`**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) player name:

```
var player_exists = $('.player__pick:contains("'+playerName+'")').length;
```

Then:

```
if (!player_exists) {
    // do the stuff...
}
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9o3Lfbnh/)</kbd>